# Re-tag/Re-version a published nuget package

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package

Once a published nuget package that is in release candidate (e.g 4.5.0-RC) status, has passed all the verification tests, we would like to change it's version to a release one like v.4.5.0 without rebuilding it from the source code.

The RC version of it, has been created like this:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o out --no-restore
dotnet pack --configuration Release --no-build --output nupkgs \p:PackageVersion=4.5.0-RC
dotnet nuget push nupkgs/org.package_one.4.5.0-RC.nupkg --api-key xxx --source "github"
```

So, is there any way to

1. pull it
2. change the version and the tag
3. push it to the remote registry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I finally manage to do:

```
Step 1 - ADD SOURCES
dotnet nuget add source -u <username> -p <pat> --store-password-in-clear-text --name github "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/<org>/index.json"

nuget sources add -Name "github" -Source "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/<org>/index.json" -username "<username>" -password "<pat>"

Step 2 - DOWNLOAD THE PACKAGE
nuget install <package-name> -OutputDirectory ./download -Version "1.0.1-1.1.0-rc-1" -Source https://nuget.pkg.github.com/<org>/index.json -DependencyVersion Ignore

Step 3 - CHANGE DIR
cd ./download/<package-name>.1.0.1-1.1.0-rc-1

Step 4 - UNZIP IT INTO A DIR
unzip <package-name>.nupkg -d repackage

Step 5 - MAKE IT EDITABLE
chmod 777 repackage/<package-name>.nuspec

STEP 6 - CHANGE THE VERSION
sed -i -e 's/\(<version>\).*\(<\/version>\)/<version>1.0.1-1.1.0<\/version>/g' repackage/<package-name>.nuspec

STEP - 7 REVERT PERMISSIONS CHANGES
chmod 000 repackage/<package-name>.nuspec

STEP - 8 ZIP IT BACK
zip -r -j <package-name>.1.0.1-1.1.0.nupkg repackage/*

STEP - 9 PUSH THE NEW PACKAGE
dotnet nuget push <package-name>.1.0.1-1.1.0.nupkg --source "github" --api-key <pat>
```

Comment: If the original package was signed, the new package will fail to extract, appearing to have been tampered with (well, technically this is true, it has been tampered with). Your specific package might not be signed, so it might work for you, but in the general case, you need to delete the `.signature.p7s` file before re-zipping.

Comment: Also, people who try this on Windows often cause problems for package consumers on Mac & Linux, because NuGet normalizes paths in the zip's central directory to use `/` as path separators, but PowerShell's `Compress-Archive` (and maybe other Windows zip apps) will use `\` path separators. So, anyone trying this on Windows, make sure your zip creation renormalizes paths to `/`, or just use NuGet to re-create the nupkg, so you don't have to re-implement all these details yourself.

Comment: @zivkan, what do you mean by "use NuGet to re-create the nupkg"?

Comment: use `nuget.exe pack whatever.nuspec`. I'm not 100% sure it'll avoid re-packing the `.signature.p7s` file, or what will happen with the Open Package Conventions files that `nuget install` would normally ignore when extracting the package. However, it will, at the very least, ensure that `\`'s are normailized to `/`.